# Validate Email Header in Python

Tags: python, regex, email

I have a RegEx for validating email addresses, but I'm really looking to validate a whole From header.  Any of these would be valid:

```
name@domain.com
<name@domain.com>
My Name <name@domain.com>
```

Is there anything out there that would validate these as valid from headers?  I'm going to look in the smtp library :)

Comment: I have to ask, why do you need to validate the headers yourself rather than letting an SMTP server do it for you? It's a rather complicated task to do the validation properly.

Comment: If you want to make sure you're validating everything properly, check the standard format: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html

Comment: We're supplying our own from address, so I need to make sure the email editors supply a proper from header/email address, otherwise the emails they send will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the posted response to work, so I've been working on this and finally got this one, which seems to work so far.  I'm sure it'll miss/catch something, but it's working for now.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9+_\-\.\ ]*[ ]*<?[a-zA-Z0-9+_\-\.]+@[0-9a-zA-Z][.-0-9a-zA-Z]*.[a-zA-Z]+>?
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that there are plenty of other valid cases of e-mail addresses beyond what you've posted.

See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20070703061025/http://www.secureprogramming.com/?action=view&feature=recipes&recipeid=1) for a recipe that may help.  Also read [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for a great discussion of parsing email addresses with a regex.  There are any number of good regexes in there that will match the uses you're looking for, imho :-)